# Laptop battery - 100% available but says charging

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, battery

My laptop charger suddenly went off while connected to the laptop, I tried to reproduce and noticed that the battery is 100% full and Windows says it is still charging.

Why does Windows keep charging the battery while at the same time says 100% available ?

---

[image]

Comment: what do you mean when you say "my charger suddenly went off?"

Comment: Charger connected to laptop, after some time, the charger indicator goes off, the charger stops charging and laptop running on battery.

Comment: Reconnecting the charger to the socket and it acted normally again.

Comment: Have you tried calibrating your battery yet? By the way, [this application](http://batterycare.net/en/) might be of interest to you. I use it to keep an eye on the wear level of my notebook battery and also keep tabs on the number of battery discharge cycles.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your notebook's battery hasn't been calibrated in a while. Follow [this guide](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00817650&tmp_task=solveCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&tool=&query=Dv5-1125em&product=3807969) to calibrate your notebook's battery.

Battery calibration instructions (from HowToGeek):

> - Charge your laptop’s battery to full — that’s 100%.
> - Let the battery rest for at least two hours, leaving the computer plugged in. This will ensure that the battery is cool and not still
>     hot from the charging process. You’re free to use your computer
>     normally while it’s plugged in.
> - Go into your computer’s power management settings and set it to automatically sleep or hibernate at 5% battery.
> - Pull the power plug and leave your computer discharging until it automatically sleeps or hibernates. You can keep using your computer
>     normally while this happens.
>
>   (Note: If you want to calibrate the battery while you aren’t using
>     the computer, be sure your computer isn’t set to automatically sleep,
>     hibernate, or turn its display off while idle. If your computer
>     automatically enters power-saving mode while you’re away, it will save
>     power and won’t discharge properly.)
> - Allow your computer to sit for five hours or so after it automatically shuts down.
> - Plug your computer back into the outlet and charge it back up to 100%. You can keep using your computer normally.
> - Ensure any power management settings are set to their normal values. For example, you probably want your computer to automatically
>     power off the display and then go to sleep when you’re not using it to
>     save battery power.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, but the question is why does Windows says charging and 100% at the same time.

Comment: when the battery isn't calibrated in a while, it could send incorrect information about its current capacity to the OS, which is probably why that happens. But you should get rid of it after you've calibrated your battery. If the problem keeps recurring and your battery charge drops abruptly and significantly in a short while when you're using your computer, it's time to get a new battery.